# Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments?

Tags: java, spring, scope, prototype, spring-java-config

Using Spring's Java Config, I need to acquire/instantiate a prototype-scoped bean with constructor arguments that are only obtainable at runtime.  Consider the following code example (simplified for brevity):

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appCtx;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    //request is already validated
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Thing thing = appCtx.getBean(Thing.class, name);

    //System.out.println(thing.getName()); //prints name
}
```

where the Thing class is defined as follows:

```
public class Thing {

    private final String name;

    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    public Thing(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Notice `name` is `final`: it can only be supplied via a constructor, and guarantees immutability.  The other dependencies are implementation-specific dependencies of the `Thing` class, and shouldn't be known to (tightly coupled to) the request handler implementation.

This code works perfectly well with Spring XML config, for example:

```
<bean id="thing", class="com.whatever.Thing" scope="prototype">
    <!-- other post-instantiation properties omitted -->
</bean>
```

How do I achieve the same thing with Java config?  The following does not work using Spring 3.x:

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Thing thing(String name) {
    return new Thing(name);
}
```

Now, I *could* create a Factory, e.g.:

```
public interface ThingFactory {
    public Thing createThing(String name);
}
```

But that *defeats the entire point of using Spring to replace the ServiceLocator and Factory design pattern*, which would be ideal for this use case.

If Spring Java Config could do this, I would be able to avoid:

- defining a Factory interface
- defining a Factory implementation
- writing tests for the Factory implementation

That's a ton of work (relatively speaking) for something so trivial that Spring already supports via XML config.

Comment: However, is there a reason you cannot just instantiate the class yourself and have to get it from Spring? Does it have dependencies on other beans?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, the `Thing` implementation is actually more complex and does have dependencies on other beans (I just omitted them for brevity).  As such, I don't want the Request handler implementation to know about them, as this would tightly couple the handler to APIs/beans it doesn't need.  I'll update the question to reflect your (excellent) question.

Comment: I am not sure if Spring allows this on a constructor, but I know you can put `@Qualifier` on parameters to a setter with `@Autowired` on the setter itself.

Comment: In Spring 4, your example with `@Bean` works. The `@Bean` method gets called with the appropriate arguments you passed to `getBean(..)`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have confirmed that this does indeed work with Spring 4.  Please feel free to submit an Answer and I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: It's not hard to inject fields marked with `@Autowired` or setters using Spring classes yourself (a few lines of code) and I've been using it for a while (with Spring 2.5 if I recall correctly) using neither of `@Bean`, `@Scope("prototype")`, `@Configuration`. I do not consider `BeanFactory.getBean(String, Object[])` reasonable since it lacks compile time checking. I will probably post an answer when I come up with the design that I can recommend (my current design has some problems).

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In a `@Configuration` class, a `@Bean` method like so

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public Thing thing(String name) {
    return new Thing(name);
}
```

is used to register a **bean definition and provide the factory for creating the bean**. The bean that it defines is only instantiated upon request using arguments that are determined either directly or through scanning that `ApplicationContext`.

In the case of a `prototype` bean, a new object is created every time and therefore the  corresponding `@Bean` method is also executed.

You can retrieve a bean from the `ApplicationContext` through its [`BeanFactory#getBean(String name, Object... args)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method which states

> Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method
> arguments, overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the
> bean definition.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **args** arguments to use if creating a prototype using explicit arguments
> to a static factory method. It is invalid to use a non-null args value
> in any other case.

In other words, for this `prototype` scoped bean, you are providing the arguments that will be used, not in the constructor of the bean class, but in the `@Bean` method invocation. (This method has very weak type guarantees since it uses a name lookup for the bean.)

Alternatively, you can use the typed [`BeanFactory#getBean(Class requiredType, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-) method which looks up the bean by type.

This is at least true for Spring versions 4+.

Note that, if you don't want to start with the `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory` for your bean retrieval, you can inject an [`ObjectProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) (since Spring 4.3).

> A variant of `ObjectFactory` designed specifically for injection points,
> allowing for programmatic optionality and lenient not-unique handling.

and use its [`getObject(Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html#getObject-java.lang.Object...-) method

> Return an instance (possibly shared or independent) of the object
> managed by this factory.
>
> Allows for specifying explicit construction arguments, along the lines
> of `BeanFactory.getBean(String, Object)`.

For example,

```
@Autowired
private ObjectProvider<Thing> things;

[...]
Thing newThing = things.getObject(name);
[...]
```

Answer (score 82):

With Spring > 4.0 and Java 8 you can do this more type-safely:

```
@Configuration    
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Function<String, Thing> thingFactory() {
        return name -> thing(name); // or this::thing
    } 

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public Thing thing(String name) {
       return new Thing(name);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@Autowired
private Function<String, Thing> thingFactory;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    //request is already validated
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Thing thing = thingFactory.apply(name);

    // ...
}
```

So now you can get your bean at runtime. This is a factory pattern of course, but you can save some time on writing specific class like `ThingFactory` (however you will have to write custom `@FunctionalInterface` to pass more than two parameters).

Comment: You basically reinvented [Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html) or [ObjectFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectFactory.html), both of which are supported by Spring.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I do not claim I have invented something remarkable, I just find this approach more fluent and clean

Comment: @RomanGolyshev my point is, you didn’t need to write any code to do this, there’re already 2 classes that exist

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar oh, I see. But you cannot pass a parameter to a `Provider` or to an `ObjectFactory`, or am I wrong? And in my example you can pass a string parameter to it (or any parameter)

Comment: AFAIK, not without writing additional code. If that’s the requirement, then the out-of-the-box implementation of both don’t do that. I missed that point in your answer, upvoted now

Comment: can you specify `Function`? Which jar does it come from?

Comment: @hakunami it comes from `java.util.function` package starting from jdk8

Comment: If you do not want to (or do not need to) use Spring bean life cycle methods (which are different for prototype beans...) you can skip `@Bean` and `Scope` annotations over the `Thing thing` method. Moreover this method can be made private to hide itself and left only factory.

Comment: @m52509791 you are correct: if you don't need it, you can completely omit method and create new instances right in the `thingFactory` lambda body

Comment: Upvoted this answer because the default approach with Spring to get prototype bean is to use ApplicationContext.getBean(...), which pollute the code and make it Spring dependent, and this contradicts Spring's philosophy of being non-invasive. This solution fulfills this intent and keeps the code Spring free except the annotations which can be replaced with JSR annotations.

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice and elegant solution for creating factory beans in Spring.
The prototype method didn't work for me: Spring would try to inject the input String.
Just having the function returning method define the function in itself was enough, though: 


    `@Bean 
    public Function<String, Thing> thingFactory() {
        return name -> new Thing (name);
    }`

Answer (score 40):

Since Spring 4.3, there is new way to do it, which was sewed for that issue.

[ObjectProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html) - It enables you just to add it as a dependency to your "argumented" Prototype scoped bean and to instantiate it using the argument.

Here is a simple example of how to use it:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf {
    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public MyPrototype createPrototype(String arg) {
        return new MyPrototype(arg);
    }
}

public class MyPrototype {
    private String arg;

    public MyPrototype(String arg) {
        this.arg = arg;
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}


@Component
public class UsingMyPrototype {
    private ObjectProvider<MyPrototype> myPrototypeProvider;

    @Autowired
    public UsingMyPrototype(ObjectProvider<MyPrototype> myPrototypeProvider) {
        this.myPrototypeProvider = myPrototypeProvider;
    }

    public void usePrototype() {
        final MyPrototype myPrototype = myPrototypeProvider.getObject("hello");
        myPrototype.action();
    }
}
```

This will of course print hello string when calling usePrototype.

Comment: What if `MyPrototype` is a `bean` that depends on other beans, which means it cannot be instantiated using `new`?

Comment: @Searene, you can always inject other beans to createPrototype, spring will inject them for you.

Comment: I believe this would be a cleanest way to do it without injecting `BeanFactory`!

Answer (score 16):

**UPDATED per comment**

First, I'm not sure why you say "this does not work" for something that works just fine in Spring 3.x.  I suspect something must be wrong in your configuration somewhere.

This works:

-- Config File:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {
    // only here to demo execution order
    private int count = 1;

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public TransferService myFirstService(String param) {
       System.out.println("value of count:" + count++);
       return new TransferServiceImpl(aSingletonBean(), param);
    }

    @Bean
    public AccountRepository aSingletonBean() {
        System.out.println("value of count:" + count++);
        return new InMemoryAccountRepository();
    }
}
```

-- Test File to execute:

```
@Test
public void prototypeTest() {
    // create the spring container using the ServiceConfig @Configuration class
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ServiceConfig.class);
    Object singleton = ctx.getBean("aSingletonBean");
    System.out.println(singleton.toString());
    singleton = ctx.getBean("aSingletonBean");
    System.out.println(singleton.toString());
    TransferService transferService = ctx.getBean("myFirstService", "simulated Dynamic Parameter One");
    System.out.println(transferService.toString());
    transferService = ctx.getBean("myFirstService", "simulated Dynamic Parameter Two");
    System.out.println(transferService.toString());
}
```

Using Spring 3.2.8 and Java 7, gives this output:

```
value of count:1
com.spring3demo.account.repository.InMemoryAccountRepository@4da8692d
com.spring3demo.account.repository.InMemoryAccountRepository@4da8692d
value of count:2
Using name value of: simulated Dynamic Parameter One
com.spring3demo.account.service.TransferServiceImpl@634d6f2c
value of count:3
Using name value of: simulated Dynamic Parameter Two
com.spring3demo.account.service.TransferServiceImpl@70bde4a2
```

So the 'Singleton' Bean is requested twice.  However as we would expect, Spring only creates it once.  The second time it sees that it has that bean and just returns the existing object.  The constructor (@Bean method) is not invoked a second time.  In deference to this, when the 'Prototype' Bean is requested from the same context object twice we see that the reference changes in the output AND that the constructor (@Bean method) IS invoked twice.

So then the question is how to inject a singleton into a prototype.  The configuration class above shows how to do that too!  You should pass all such references into the constructor.  This will allow the created class to be a pure POJO as well as making the contained reference objects immutable as they should be.  So the transfer service might look something like:

```
public class TransferServiceImpl implements TransferService {

    private final String name;

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public TransferServiceImpl(AccountRepository accountRepository, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        // system out here is only because this is a dumb test usage
        System.out.println("Using name value of: " + this.name);

        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }
    ....
}
```

If you write Unit Tests you will be ever so happy you created the classes this without all the @Autowired.  If you do need autowired components keep those local to the java config files.

This will call the method below in the BeanFactory.  Note in the description how this is intended for your exact use case.

```
/**
 * Return an instance, which may be shared or independent, of the specified bean.
 * <p>Allows for specifying explicit constructor arguments / factory method arguments,
 * overriding the specified default arguments (if any) in the bean definition.
 * @param name the name of the bean to retrieve
 * @param args arguments to use if creating a prototype using explicit arguments to a
 * static factory method. It is invalid to use a non-null args value in any other case.
 * @return an instance of the bean
 * @throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException if there is no such bean definition
 * @throws BeanDefinitionStoreException if arguments have been given but
 * the affected bean isn't a prototype
 * @throws BeansException if the bean could not be created
 * @since 2.5
 */
Object getBean(String name, Object... args) throws BeansException;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I think you misunderstood the question.  The most important part of the question is that a runtime value must be supplied as a constructor argument when acquiring (instantiating) the prototype.

Comment: I updated my reply.  Actually it seemed like handling the runtime value was done correctly so I did leave that part out.  It is explicitly supported though as you can see from the updates and output from the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve a similar effect just by using an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html):

```
@Component
class ThingFactory {
    private final SomeBean someBean;

    ThingFactory(SomeBean someBean) {
        this.someBean = someBean;
    }

    Thing getInstance(String name) {
        return new Thing(name);
    }

    class Thing {
        private final String name;

        Thing(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        void foo() {
            System.out.format("My name is %s and I can " +
                    "access bean from outer class %s", name, someBean);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create a **qualified bean** you can do it this way:

```java
@Configuration
public class ThingConfiguration {

   @Bean
   @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public Thing simpleThing(String name) {
       return new Thing(name);
   }

   @Bean
   @Scope(SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
   public Thing specialThing(String name) {
       Thing thing = new Thing(name);
       // some special configuration
       return thing;
   }

}

// Usage 

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
((DefaultListableBeanFactory) beanFactory).getBean("specialThing", Thing.class, "name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer with a slightly different approach. 
That is a follow up of this [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311147/create-request-scoped-beans-from-a-java-8-function/) that refers this question itself.

Yes, as that was said you can declare the prototype bean that accepts a parameter in a `@Configuration` class that allows to create a new bean at each injection.
That will make this `@Configuration`  class a factory and to not give this factory too much responsibilities, this should not include other beans.

```
@Configuration    
public class ServiceFactory {

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Thing thing(String name) {
       return new Thing(name);
   }

}
```

But you can also inject that configuration bean to create `Thing`s :

```
@Autowired
private ServiceFactory serviceFactory;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    //request is already validated
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Thing thing = serviceFactory.thing(name); // create a new bean at each invocation
    // ...    
}
```

It is both type-safe and concise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is a Spring anti-pattern.  Config objects should not 'leak' into application code - they exist to configure your application object graph and interface with Spring constructs.  This is akin to XML classes in your application beans (i.e. another config mechanism).  That is, If Spring comes along with another config mechanism, you'd have a to refactor your application code - a clear indicator this violates separation of concerns.  It is better to have your Config create instances of a Factory/Function interface and inject the Factory - no tight coupling to config.

Comment: 1)I completely agree that in the general case, configuration objects have not to leak as a field. But in this specific case, injecting a configuration object that defines one and only one bean to produce prototype beans, IHMO it makes completely sense : this configuration class becomes a factory. Where is the separation of concerns issue if it makes only that ?  ...

Comment: ... 2) About "That is, If Spring comes along with another config mechanism, ", it is a wrong argument because when you decide to use a framework in your application, you couple your application with that. So in any case, you will also have to refactor any Spring applications that relies on `@Configuration` if that mechanism changed.

Comment: ...3) The answer you accepted proposes to use `BeanFactory#getBean()`. But that is well worse in terms of coupling since that is a factory that allows to get/instantiate any beans of the application and not only which one the current bean needs. With such an usage you can mix responsibilities of your class very easily since dependencies that it may pull are unlimited, which is really not advised but exceptional case.

Comment: @ davidxxx - I accepted the answer years ago, before JDK 8 and Spring 4 were de-facto.  Roman's answer above is more correct for modern Spring usages.  With regards to your statement "because when you decide to use a framework in your application, you couple your application with that" is quite antithetical to the Spring team's recommendations and the Java Config best practices - ask Josh Long or Jeurgen Hoeller if you get a chance to speak to them in person (I have, and I can assure you they explicitly advise to *not* couple your app code to Spring whenever possible).  Cheers.

Comment: Best and simplest answer IMHO. Disagree with 1),  cglib instrumentation of a config bean is not for the decorum. Methods are meant to be called inside and outside the config bean. Nothing in the spring doc recommands to not inject a configuration bean. Spring has many way to instanciate a bean, `@Configuration` is one of them. If `@Configuration` is the issue, one can simply create a `@Factory` annotation annoted with `@Configuration`... Roman answer is an unnecessary abstraction over a valid one with the downside of using generic and Function1 to  FunctionX

Answer (score 0):

Nice solutions until now. But I want to post yet another alternative.
Spring has the `@Lookup` annotation. From javadoc:

> An annotation that indicates 'lookup' methods, to be overridden by the
> container to redirect them back to the BeanFactory for a getBean call.

you can declare your `Thing` as prototype bean:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Thing {

    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    public Thing(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

then you can create instances by creating a method like `createThing` below  in any other bean:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appCtx;

    public void onRequest(Request request) {
        //request is already validated
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        Thing thing = createThing(name);

        //System.out.println(thing.getName()); //prints name
    }
    
    //or public. And can be put in any @Component (including @Configuration)
    @Lookup
    protected Thing createThing(String name) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Method implemented by Spring.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

in your beans xml file use the attribute ***scope="prototype"***