# create map bean with a factory in a @Configuration class

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, annotations, javabeans

Trying to create a map bean with prototype scope in config class

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {

   public SpringConfig() {
   }


   @Bean
   @Scope("prototype")
   public Map<String, Composite> getCompositesMap() {
      return new LinkedHashMap<String, Composite>();
   }
}
```

But spring complains

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite] found for dependency [map with value type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, mappedName=, description=, name=, type=class java.lang.Object, authenticationType=CONTAINER, lookup=)}
```

How does one define a prototype map bean using annotations only (no xml)?

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because Spring is trying to inject `Composite` into your method, but there is no such bean that corresponds to that class.

You can add a prototype scoped bean inside your `SpringConfig` class - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu).

Comment: Understood that one can provide a "Composite" bean.  That is not the issue.  The issue is that there is no need to ask for a "Composite" bean in the first place.  The Map is empty.