# How can we create a factory pattern to return a spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns

I want to have a Factory class, which has a method getInstance.

```
public PersonService getInstance(String someParameter1, Object someParameter 2, ...)
```

I dont want to instantiate a factory class. i just want to call a method on my factory like

```
PersonService service = MyFactory.getInstance(..) // some arguments passed
```

How we can achieve this in spring?

Comment: Make `getInstance` method `static`

Comment: In Spring, you're supposed to define a FactoryBean

Comment: what kind of scope for your bean do you expect "prototype" ?

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, you're supposed to let the container construct your instances.

You should implement a [`FactoryBean<PersonService>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) and add it to your context configuration.

Instead of calling `getInstance()`/`getObject()` yourself, just have Spring inject the service via `@Autowired` where you need it.

Comment: But i need to return a service based on some condition in my factory class. I dont want my client to know which service impl i am returning, hence factory makes sense. If i were to use Factory Bean, then how can i impose those conditions which are provided to my factory my client.

Comment: Unless you can be more specific, all I can say is "by writing the code".