# How do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments? With getBean(String name, Object... args)?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring-ioc

How do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments? With `getBean(String name, Object... args)`?
My question is a consequence of **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu).**

**Why is this approach not used or mentioned in the [Spring IoC documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html)?**

Is this a **normal approach**? Is there a **more correct approach** for create a prototype @Bean with runtime arguments?

If it is **not** normal approach, so could you explain why? 
Pay attention, what i need set my arguments through constructor, **not** through setters.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appCtx;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    //request is already validated
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Thing thing = appCtx.getBean(Thing.class, name);

    //System.out.println(thing.getName()); //prints name
}
```

-

```
public class Thing {

    private final String name;

    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    public Thing(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, the answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad/812573?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Basically, you're still disobeying DI if you do this with prototype beans

Comment: @Dovmo Looked this answer. But I don't understand how else can I create objects that come from a client? That have different data all the time.

Comment: In terms of constructor injection, you don't have many other options, afaik. I'm only aware of a method like I suggested below

Comment: @Dovmo Do you mean we should will have to refuse to implement your data inject to constructor if we use Dependency Injection?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Since you need to use the constructor, it looks like the only option for you is to use `getBean`

Answer (score 0):

In terms of constructor injection, no. However, you can give `Thing` an `init` method and use an `ObjectFactory`:

```
@Autowired
private ObjectFactory<Thing> thingFactory;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    //request is already validated
    Thing thing = thingFactory.getObject();
    thing.init("name");

    //System.out.println(thing.getName()); //prints name
}
```

With thing being:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Thing {

    private String name;

    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    @Autowired
    private AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    public init(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, the `name` can't be `final` since it's not via the constructor. Would love to see if there are better ways to do this with `constructor injection`.

Comment: Why not? Can you explain why? I need inject through constructor, not through setters.

Comment: Whats wrong with approach `Thing thing = appCtx.getBean(Thing.class, name);"` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the help of a bean factory:

```
@Configuration
public class ThingProvider {

    @Bean
    @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Thing create(String name) {
        return new Thing(name);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @Autowired
    private ThingProvider thingProvider;

    public void onRequest(Request request) {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        Thing thing = myProvider.create(name);
    }

}
```

What is often brought forward as an argument against `appCtx.getBean(Thing.class, name)` is that it requires to hard-wire Spring specific classes. Plus, there is no compile time check in case the `Thing` constructor changes.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, your `Thing` class might mix constructor dependencies and runtime arguments, something like this:

```
public class Thing {

    private final SomeComponent someComponent;
    private final AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    private final String name;

    @Autowired
    public Thing(SomeComponent someComponent,
                 AnotherComponent anotherComponent,
                 String name) {
        this.someComponent = someComponent;
        this.anotherComponent = anotherComponent;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    } 
}
```

Then you can wrap them in configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SomeComponent someComponent;

    @Autowired
    private final AnotherComponent anotherComponent;

    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public Thing createThing(String name) {
        return new Thing(someComponent, anotherComponent, name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Autowired
private BeanFactory beanFactory;

public void onRequest(Request request) {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    Thing thing = beanFactory.getBean(Thing.class, name);
}
```

It supposed to work, not sure if this is a good practice though.