# Trace the request begin & end in Pub-Sub model - issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to trace the begining and end of a single operation. As the receiver receives 100 reqeust/seconds, i am unable to achive it. Kindly help

By the time first process ends, second process enters and changing the UUID value.

So i am unable to trace the begin and end of a single message/request.

This is not a Web application so can't use 'reqest' scope for Trace class, my application is a pub-sub model. Here is a sample application.

```
public class MainClass {
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public Receiver getEventHubReceiver(Trace trace, SomeOtherClass classex) {
        return new Receiver(trace, classex);
    }
}

@Component
class Trace{

    String traceid;

    public void setTraceid(String traceid) {
        this.traceid = traceid;
    }

    public void trace(String msg){
        System.out.println(traceid+" : Tracing : "+msg);
    }
}

class Receiver{
    private final SomeOtherClass classex;
    private final Trace trace;

    Receiver(Trace trace, SomeOtherClass classex){
        this.trace= trace;
        this.classex = classex;
    }

    //This is a callback method invoked by server internally.
    public void receiver(){
        trace.setTraceid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        trace.trace("reached Receiver..started");
        classex.invoke(); //==> I don't want to pass the Trace object here, same object should be used by multiple classes.
        trace.trace("reached Receiver..completed");
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass{

    @Autowired
    private Trace trace; // ==> ISSUE -- Behaving as a single ton.

    public void invoke(){
        trace.trace("Reached SomeOtherClass - started");
        someLongRunProcess(); // it take almost 3-5 seconds to complete this.
        trace.trace("Reached SomeOtherClass - completed");
    }

    private void someLongRunProcess() {
       //DB invoke option
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `prototype` scope for your `Trace` component?  The prototype scope should allow you to have a new bean created for each request that you process. For more information, see [this answer on prototype scope instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184027/645344).