# Defining constructor in prototype bean

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

Using SpringBoot, I have a Component bean that is defined as `@Scope("protoype")`.  It also injects another prototype bean

The class is defined as

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyClass{
    @Autowired
    public BeanFactory beanFactory

    private InjectedBean injectedBean

    public MyClass(DataObj data) {
        this.injectedBean = beanFactory.getBean(InjectedBean.class, data)
    }
}
```

However, IntelliJ complains about the data field on the constructor: `Could not autowire. No beans of 'DataObj' type found.`.  But DataObj is a POJO.  I pass it in at runtime in order to create the bean.  Am I defining the constructor incorrectly?

**Update**

Had the same problem doing it this way.  It still wants to treat DataObj as a bean on the factory constructor class. Doesn't matter if I annotate the class with @Component or @Configuration

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
    @Autowired
    public BeanFactory beanFactory

    private InjectedBean injectedBean

    public MyClass(InjectedBean injectedBean) {
        this.injectedBean = injectedBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyClass myClass(DataObj data) {
        InjectedBean injectedBean = beanFactory.getBean(InjectedBean.class, data)
        return new MyClass(injectedBean);
    }
}
```

Also tried this example from that same link:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Function<DataObj, MyClass> thingFactory() {
        return data-> myClass(data); //
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public MyClass myClass(DataObj data) {
        return new MyClass(data);
    }
}
```

**Update**
I think I resolved this with some information in [Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu/22184027#22184027).  Part of my problem is that I tried to put the factory bean in the Component itself, which doesn't work

In other words

```
@Component
public class MyClass{
    @Autowired
    public BeanFactory beanFactory

    private InjectedBean injectedBean

    public MyClass(InjectedBean injectedBean) {
        this.injectedBean = injectedBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public MyClass myClass(DataObj data) {
        InjectedBean injectedBean = beanFactory.getBean(InjectedBean.class, data)
        return new MyClass(injectedBean);
    }
}
```

In this cass, Spring tries to create a MyClass bean because of the @Component annotation, but another MyClass bean due to the @Bean annotation.
So I moved the @Bean to another class

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Function<DataObj, MyClass> thingFactory() {
        return data-> myClass(data); //
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public MyClass myClass(DataObj data) {
        return new MyClass(data);
    }
}
```

This appears to work, but IntelliJ still complains about DataObj. This might be an Intellij issue

Comment: Please see if solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184027/924036 can work for you with some modifications.

Comment: I read that page, and it all makes sense when I read it, but I can't get it to work.  See my update above.  I tried using a factory class instead of a constructor, but I get the same problem