# IntelliJ complaining about Autoworing

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, autowired

I've got a class like this (from [Spring Java Config: how do you create a prototype-scoped @Bean with runtime arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155832/spring-java-config-how-do-you-create-a-prototype-scoped-bean-with-runtime-argu/22184027#22184027))

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public Function<DataObj, MyClass> myClassFactory() {
        return data-> myClass(data); 
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public MyClass myClass(DataObj data) {
        return new MyClass(data);
    }
}
```

However, IntelliJ (2020.3) complains about `DataObj data`  - `Could not autowire.  No beans of 'DataObj' type found`.  DataObj is not a bean.  It is a runtime object that passes data to the construction of the bean.  Even if I leave this IntelliJ error as an error (as opposed to a warning), it still works.  Why is IntelliJ complaining about this?  Is there a way to suppress the error (without turning off the inspection)?

Comment: Please try https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/. If the issue persists, file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the reproducible test case. You can suppress inspections for lines/methods/classes, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html .

Comment: Forgot to mention what release I'm using.  I'm at 2020.3, which is the most current, other than EAP.  I don't want to suppress the warning in all cases.  Couldn't find an annotation to suppress just this instance.  I also wanted to post here just to make sure I'm not doing something wrong

Comment: The suggestion was to try the EAP since several related issues were fixed there. It's an RC right now and will be released next week.

Comment: You can suppress it for statement [from the context menu](https://resources.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2020.3/suppress-inspection.png).

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Weren't sure if you were just saying to try it, just in case, or you had actual reason to believe it might fix it.

Comment: As for suppressing, yes, I Know that is frequently an option, but I don't see that choice [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4r505sw8ur3m0u/2021-03-31%2016_03_20-.png?dl=0)

Comment: You can suppress is for parameter or method.